# Is it possible to run taskkill to target a specific chrome window that was just opened?

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file

I would like to do this just in case I'm working on something in a separate chrome window and don't want to lose my progress.

What I'm trying to do is open 5 messenger chats at a time in a chrome window so I can msg clients, and then what I want is that chrome window to close and a new one to open with another 5 messenger chats. All while any other chrome window I opened prior is unaffected.

I know how to kill chrome completely and trigger a new 5 which is what I'll do if this isn't possible.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Yes and no. Chrome creates separate processes and taskkill can be used against just one process. The problem is that there's no way to figure out which process is which from just cli alone. Chome has a build in task manager, and you can actually use that one to do it, but there's no cli for it.

Comment: May be this can give you an idea but in vbscript [How to gently close Chrome using CMD or VBS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62551720/3080770)